# Grok parse error while parsing Apache logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

OK, so I am in need of some help in figuring out why Logstash is giving me a parse error when I have tested it on the [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). This has to do with a custom log from Apache.

Below is the raw log entry:

```
57.85.212.139 tst.testing.com [13/Mar/2015:10:10:55 -0600] "POST /app/cp/authenticate/updateLog HTTP/1.1" 200 444 195268 "-" "-"
```

Here is the Grok pattern:

```
(%{IP:clientip}|-) %{HOSTNAME:host} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "((?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}))|-)" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) %{NUMBER:duration} "(%{DATA:referer}|-)" "(%{DATA:useragent}|-)"
```

Below is the error from Logstash:

```
{"tags":["_grokparsefailure"],"@version":1,"@timestamp":"2015-03-13T16:10:55.650Z","host":"EOA-ELB-TEST","file":"/var/log/apache2/access.log","message":"57.85.212.139 tst.testing.com [13/Mar/2015:10:10:55 -0600] \"POST /app/cp/authenticate/updateLog HTTP/1.1\" 200 444 216340 \"-\" \...
```

This makes no sense to me. Why would it pass on the validator but fail in Logstash?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that the only grok{} in your config?  Could it be that the other one is throwing the error?  Check out tag_on_failure.

Comment: Are you escaping the double quotes in your Logstash configuration? Because the expression works fine when I insert it into a Logstash configuration and escape the double quotes. Editing your post to include the actual configuration would be helpful.